# Glide Binding Adapter doesn't show the url pictures

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-glide, android-binding-adapter

So i want to have pictures show on my view from the Unsplash API. The thing is the API call is working but the pictures just don't show. All it is showing is the error placeholder.

[image]

Here is the Binding Adapter

```
@BindingAdapter("pictureOfDay")
fun CustomImage.displayPicture(carouselItem: CarouselItem?) {
    if (carouselItem?.urls == "images")
        Glide.with(context).load(carouselItem.urls)
            .error(R.drawable.glowing_x)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(this)
    else setImageResource(R.drawable.glowing_x)



}
```

Any ideas are welcome, thank you.

Comment: Your code checks `carouselItem?.urls == "images"` so then it trys to `.load` a string `images` instead of a valid url?

Comment: Well, I would like it to load up the url's from the API, could that be were the problem is?

Comment: Have you added the INTERNET permission? Also try to use `http` instead of `https` in image URLs

Comment: I have, It looks like it was a problem with the XML file. I didn't assign it to the right variable, thus I have nothing to show. I think another question comes to be how to alter the binding adapter to a string since my binding adapter for the view doesn't take in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up solving it. I had to change up my binding adapter, so that it accepted a string. Something like this...

```
@BindingAdapter("pictureOfDay")
fun CustomImage.setDisplayPicture(urlPic: String?)  {
    if (urlPic != null)
        Glide.with(context).load(urlPic)
            .error(R.drawable.glowing_x)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(this)
    else setImageResource(R.drawable.glowing_x)



}
```

Works perfectly fine now.